# What is the gender of the plug on the DC cord of this power supply?

Tags: power-supply, connector

Regarding the supply [here](https://docs.rs-online.com/05a8/A700000006464057.pdf), the model which ends with P1M. I cannot figure out whether it is a male plug or female:

[image]

The photo looks like it is female:

[image]

But in another vendor here, they mention center pin:

[image]

I was just looking for a panel mount counterpart of this, but Im stuck at this step. Is the barrel plug male or female?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a female plug.

Hole in the center = socket - female.

[image: Female plug]

[Source](https://docs.rs-online.com/05a8/A700000006464057.pdf)

Don't feel bad: a lot of people are confused by coaxial power barrel connectors.

According to the specs, the plug has an outer diameter of 5.5 mm and the matching male jack has an inner pin with a 2.5 mm diameter.

> looking for a panel mount counterpart

Digikey offers these 5 parts: [panel-mount male coaxial barrel power jack, 2.5 x 5.5 mm](https://www.digikey.com/short/7380f0tj).

> But in another vendor here, they mention center pin:

> Center-pin length: 11 mm

What they really mean is "barrel length: 11 mm". That is the length of the contact area of the plug: the distance from the tip of the plug to its base against the plastic mold.